# Inserting a div element with dynamic id in JQuery

Tags: jquery

How can i insert a div element with dynamic ID inside another div element using
     JQuery?

Comment: Where the dynamic name is coming from?

Comment: can you provide some HTML markup examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to create that div:

```
$('<div></div>').attr('id','my-funky-id').appendTo('parentselector');
// or
$('parentSelector').append($('<div id="'+my_id+'">'));/// my_id = var holding the id
```

if you already have that div, but you want to insert it into another element (move it) :

```
$('#'+my_id).appendTo('parentSelector');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#' + id).appendTo('div.your-other-div');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $divToAppend=  $("#divId"); //selector code

var divContents=$('<div></div>').attr('id','my-funky-id').html("<h1>new Div</h1>");

$divToAppend.append(divContents);
```

http://jsbin.com/oxiqey/4/edit#javascript,html

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "dynamic id", if you mean a random id then something like this should work:

```
$('<div></div>').prop('id', 'd' + Math.ceil(Math.random()*20000)).appendTo($('#idofdivtoinsertinto'));
```